# Appending strings mid function

Tags: ida

I'm using Ida Freeware. The string should not be changed in `.data` section. Basically I need to append a few letters to a string mid function. Currently it looks like this:
[image: Instructions]

First I would like to test my theory. How can I change the string in memory for just this function call?

Later on:
I generated a simple asm from this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

char string[] = "filterscripts/%s";

void fun(char filename[])
{
  char result[128];
  strncpy(result, string, sizeof result);
  strncat(result, ".amx", sizeof result);
}

int main() {
  fun("Shorter");
}
```

`i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -S -Wall main.c`

Resulting in

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .globl  _string
    .data
    .align 4
_string:
    .ascii "filterscripts/%s\0"
    .text
    .globl  _fun
    .def    _fun;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_fun:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %edi
    subl    $148, %esp
    movl    $128, 8(%esp)
    movl    $_string, 4(%esp)
    leal    -136(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _strncpy
    leal    -136(%ebp), %eax
    movl    $-1, %ecx
    movl    %eax, %edx
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    %edx, %edi
    repnz scasb
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    notl    %eax
    leal    -1(%eax), %edx
    leal    -136(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    $2020434222, (%eax)
    movb    $0, 4(%eax)
    nop
    addl    $148, %esp
    popl    %edi
    popl    %ebp
    ret
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
    .ascii "Shorter\0"
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _fun
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 5.3.1 20160211"
    .def    _strncpy;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

I could identify either strncpy or snprintf function calls, put the ".amx" in the `.data` section somewhere, and use a trampoline to put parts of the above code to do it, but are there more streamlined and acknowledged ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood the problem correctly but one option could be to inject the final, changed string somewhere in memory and patch the `push` instruction to use the new address.